# I want to open submenu on hover of menu item, but it's not opening

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, submenu

Hi I am making menu and submenu. I want to open submenu on hover of menu item, but it's not opening! it was wondering if you could help me on this

```css
   
.womendress: hover > .menu1 {
 display: block;
}
.menu1 {
 display:  none;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 500%;
 height: 300px;
 right: 0px;
 top : 50px;
 z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="womendress"> پوشاک زنانه
      <ul class="menu1">
        <li class="tshirt">تیشرت </li>             
        <li>شلوار</li>
        <li>پیراهن</li>
        <li>سارافون</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> تخفیفات </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Put your actual code in the post so we have a [mcve], not screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between `.womandress:` and `hover` in the hover rule - remove that. Apart from that the settings for the submenu look a bit impractical... (should have `position: absolute`, no `float`, less width etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu > ul,
#cssmenu > ul li,
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.hover,
#cssmenu > ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
/* Align last drop down RTL */
#cssmenu > ul > li.last ul ul {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 99%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.last ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.last {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: auto;
  right: 99%;
}
/* Theme Styles */
#cssmenu > ul {
  border-top: 4px solid #3fa338;
  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%, #040404 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1e1e1e), color-stop(100%, #040404));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%, #040404 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #1e1e1e 0%, #040404 100%);
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 22px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:hover {
  background-color: #3fa338;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:link,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:visited {
  color: white;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul li li {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.hover,
#cssmenu > ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #3fa338;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul a:link,
#cssmenu > ul a:visited {
  color: #9A9A9A;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul a:hover {
  color: #9A9A9A;
}
#cssmenu > ul a:active {
  color: #9A9A9A;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  border: 1px solid #CCC \9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu" class="align-right">
  <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> پوشاک زنانه</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">تیشرت</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">شلوار</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">پیراهن</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">سارافون</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dollar"></i> تخفیفات</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```